# Can i assign a cloud function service account in project A to communicate with resources in project B?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What i am trying to do here is i created a cloud function with trigger set to pubsub. so whenever a bucket is created with no encryption the cloud function deletes the respective storage bucket. This works fine for a project, but i am thinking to do the same for all projects inside a folder?? So I created a sink at folder level and routing the logs to a topic, created a cloud function in the same place where the topic is and set it as a trigger to CF. The place where i am stuck is the permissions that needs to be assigned to my cloud function service account, so that it can delete the buckets in other projects tooo...

Comment: Just add the needed permissions to the service account at folder level, in that way the function will perform the needed actions to every project under that folder (inheritance)

Comment: The permissions are the same, the difference is at what level you grant them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grant the Cloud Functions service account at the Folder level and allow the role Storage Admin to let it delete the bucket that you detect not compliant in the whole folder.